# The WebView running in the emulator in Android studio cannot access internet, but Chrome can?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview

I installed Android studio 1.0.1 and followed this page https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/gettingstarted to wrap a website to an app.

However, I got the following error when running it in emulator.

> Webpage not available
>
> The webpage at https://..... could not be loaded because:
>
> net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

However, I tried to click the link and it launched the website in Chrome without any problem.

Comment: Have you tried to put permission inside your manifest to access Internet?

Comment: Try http:// instead of https://

Comment: I tried to change the url to `mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");` and it works without any problem.

Comment: It seems you may need permissions to access that URL. let's take it as your own server URL. If it is your customized webpage make sure that URL needs port number or not. please paste all error log.

Comment: But the chome in the emulator and open the page without any problem.

Answer (score 10):

This may sound kind of obvious, but make sure 3G is turned on in your emulator:[image]

To do so, turn on Cellular Data (on is the switch to the right):

[image]

Then notice the 3G symbol shows up above the signal strength symbol:
[image]

I've been trying to manage connection state and stumbled onto this question and know that's a possible reason for that error. It's a little late, but hopefully helps someone down the line.

Comment: I can't believe it was this stupidly simple, but @SumNone's solution is what solved it for me. I was seeing on certain networks, like hotels, etc. that I was getting NameResolutionFailure errors. I never thought to switch the emulator to cellular mode instead of just assuming that WiFi mode would work. WiFi mode seems to work in most cases, but in some environments, it doesn't. I'm using the Visual Studio Emulator for Android. I enabled cell data through the settings panel on that emulator's bezel.

Answer (score 3):

It may be a bit late, but still.
You have to make sure that you included ALL the following permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, you need to connect to your VPN provider to get rid of `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` error. This is unrelated to the host VPN connection for the host computer if you're at some emulator. You need VPN at the emulator's Android, too.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you've given access to internet in manifest.xml, and still emulator can't access internet, this solution worked for me on windows 7:

Click Start -->Run, type in cmd, press OK. Copy and paste this into the Command prompt: netsh winsock reset catalog Press Enter Then copy and paste this in: netsh int ip reset reset.log Press Enter. When finished restart your computer.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bit late, but my solution was to add the port to the address: https://www.XXXXX.com:443